# PLACES_API_KEY_INVALID shown but everything seems to be done right

Tags: java, android

My app uses the Google Places API to function however when I use the line `placeLikelihoods.getStatus().getStatusMessage()` , I get the message PLACES_API_KEY_INVALID. I've been googling for days and can't find a solution. When I go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=myprojectdebug and click on my project, I am redirected to a page that shows my API key, the date I made it and my email used to make it.

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="censored b/c its got some private stuff in name">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-deta
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="My 39 character API key is here" />
</application>
```

What am I doing wrong? I feel like giving up but I also want to know what's wrong

EDIT: Found the problem however I can't fix it. I didn't use the proper keytool command shown here https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158862  but when I run this command it gives me an error because my account name has a space between my first and last name thanks to me using a microsoft account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i got your error. You misspell meta-data. Check your tag, you wrote 'meta-deta'

Comment: I had a similar problem. Drove me nuts, which is a short ride. Instead of 'com.google.android.geo.API_KEY', I had 'com.google.android.geo.api_key'. Capitalization matters.

Answer (score 2):

check this one in your manifest file i placed

```
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
```

instead of this (place below one and check spelling)

```
android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml file like

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/api_key"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Have you enable/activate google place api?

[image: Google Place Dev Console]

2) Did you keep switching your workstation? If you run your code using another pc (not the original one you use to generate api key), you need to request new API key because the debug key has changed.

Comment: For some reason it keeps disabling itself.

Comment: Now I'm getting something about the meta-data tag in the logcat. Could you write out the proper meta-data tag because I have  <meta-deta
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="39RandomLetterAPIkeyishere" />

Comment: My meta data looks like this. Probably similar to your meta data. <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyBTWDy-udxyQDHW_be8hMhCNx1Dpv_WRbk" />. Dont worry about the key, the key is invalid.

Comment: Ok, i got your error. You misspell meta-data. Check your tag, you wrote 'meta-deta'.

Comment: I feel really stupid now. After days of searching, it was a simple typo in my manifest. If you want to, put your comment as an actual answer so I can close this question.